# Set RadioButton in standard Windows installer dialog

Tags: custom-action, windows-installer

There is a Windows installer project which has a standard dialog added to it (VsdCustom2ButtonDlg.wid).
This dialog has two RadioButtons for user to choose Option1 or Option2.
I'm passing RadioButton selected by user to the installer's custom action and it works - ok.

**Question:** when there is a version of s/w already installed using say Option2 and user is installing newer build - I want this dialog to show Option2.
This means I need to set corresponding RadioButton in the dialog.
Is there a way to do this?

P.S.: there is a msi file and Setup.exe as an outcome of the installer.
I know I can run command like this and it will show me Option2 selected:

```
msiexec /i mysoft.msi INSTALLTYPE=Option2
```

What I need is to have current option selected when user runs Setup.exe.
Any help.

[image: Standard 2 button dialog example]

Comment: How do you tell that during the previous install Option 2 was selected?

Comment: @KenWhite: read some value from existing config file or registry.